# Error in the console: Parameter is not of type Blob

Tags: javascript, file-io

```
<script>
        var file = document.getElementById("userFile").files[0];
        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.readAsArrayBuffer(file);
        var byteArray = reader.result;
        console.log(byteArray);
</script>
```

This code produces this error in the console: Failed to execute 'readAsArrayBuffer' on 'FileReader': parameter 1 is not of type 'Blob'.

To my understanding, a FileReader can accept both a Blob and File as a parameter because the File interface is based upon Blob.

Comment: waiting for DOM loaded?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`FileReader` requires the use of it's [.onload property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader/onload) to trigger a callback when `readAsArrayBuffer` (and other FileReader methods) has completed. The snippet below includes an example of how it could be used in tandem with the onChange event for a file input:

```js
const input = document.getElementById('userFile');
const reader = new FileReader();

input.onchange = function() {
  const file = input.files[0];
  reader.readAsArrayBuffer(file);
};

reader.onload = function() {
  const resultArray = new Int8Array(reader.result);
  document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = resultArray;
};
```

```html
<input type="file" id="userFile"/>
<h4>File Data:</h4>
<span id="result"/>
```